# Accessing Oozie JMS notification through shell script

Tags: shell, oozie, jms-topic

I am in process of Automating Oozie workflow, while generating the result for 100's of workflow during automation it is imperative to know the state of each oozie job, I have identified that oozie JMS notification can help us, oozie JMS notification are publish on Topics and my query is there anyway where we can get the notification through Shell script.
Or going through Java code is only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oozie JMS notification are ActiveMQ based, If you are using hortonworks data platform, there are problems with ActiveMQ jar files 
please take a look at http://techuniqe.blogspot.com/2014/10/configuring-apache-oozie-40-to-generate.html

ActiveMQ supports lot of scripting technology you might want to try Stomp Client http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-access-activemq-from-ruby-perl-python-php.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to send notification to MessageBroker (say ActiveMQ) from Oozie then **question simply boils down to** **accessing Message Broker** and becomes irrelevant to oozie.
You cannot access MessageBroker from shell script alone.

There is a sample Notification Consumer (Java based) mentioned at oozie documentation - http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_JMSNotifications.html